Application of the Principle of Inclusion/Exclusion and the Binomial Theorem in Combinatorial Proofs

Consider a set $Z=X \cup Y$, where $X=\left\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\right\}$ is a set of blue elements and $Y=$ $\left\{y_1, \ldots, y_m\right\}$ is a set of red elements.


(a) How many subsets of $Z$ consist of red elements only?


(b) Let $S$ be all the $k$-subsets of $Z$. Let $E_i$ be the $k$-subsets that contain $x_i$. Using the Principle of Inclusion/Exclusion, find $\left|S \backslash\left\{\cup_{i=1}^n E_i\right\}\right|$.
Theorem (Inclusion/Exclusion). The number of elements of $S$ not in any of the subsets $E_1, \ldots, E_r$ is
$$
N-N_1+N_2-N_3+\cdots+(-1)^r N_r=\sum_{i=0}^r(-1)^i N_i .
$$


(c) Deduce that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
i
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
m+n-i \\
k-i
\end{array}\right)= \begin{cases}\left(\begin{array}{c}
m \\
k
\end{array}\right), & \text { if } m \geq k \\
0, & \text { if } m<k\end{cases}
$$


(d) Give an alternate proof of the formula in (c) using the Binomial Theorem.

My question: Is (d) correct?
(a) When considering subsets of a set $Z$ which is a union of two sets $X$ and $Y$, where $X$ represents blue elements and $Y$ represents red elements, for the question about how many subsets of $Z$ consist of red elements only we can focus solely on the set $Y$. Each element in a set can either be included or excluded when forming a subset. This binary choice (include or not include) for each element leads to a total of $2^m$ possible subsets for a set with $m$ elements. This includes the subset containing no elements at all, known as the empty set. If we want only non-empty subsets, we would subtract the empty set from the total count, resulting in $2^m-1$ subsets of red elements only.
(b) We aim to find the number of $k$-subsets that contain none of the elements $x_i$ from $X$, that is, $\left|S \backslash\left\{\cup_{i=1}^n E_i\right\}\right|$.
According to the Principle of Inclusion/Exclusion, we can calculate this number by starting with the total number of $k$-subsets, then systematically subtracting the subsets that contain at least one $x_i$, adding back the over-corrections for subsets containing multiple $x_i \mathrm{~s}$, and so on.
Thus, the total number of $k$-subsets of $Z$ is $\left(\begin{array}{c}m+n \\ k\end{array}\right)$, as $Z$ contains $m+n$ elements in total.
The number of $k$-subsets that contain at least one specific $x_i$ is $\left(\begin{array}{c}m+n-1 \\ k-1\end{array}\right)$, as we pick an $x_i$ and then choose the remaining $k-1$ elements from the other $m+n-1$ elements.
Next, for any pair $x_i$ and $x_j$, the number of $k$-subsets that contain both is $\left(\begin{array}{c}m+n-2 \\ k-2\end{array}\right)$, and so forth.
Therefore, according to the Principle of Inclusion/Exclusion, the number of desired $k$-subsets is: $$
\left|S \backslash\left\{\cup_{i=1}^n E_i\right\}\right|=\left(\begin{array}{c}
m+n \\
k
\end{array}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
m+n-1 \\
k-1
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
2
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
m+n-2 \\
k-2
\end{array}\right)-\cdots+(-1)^n\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
n
\end{array}\right)
$$
So this =  $$
\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
i
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
m+n-i \\
k-i
\end{array}\right)
$$
This continues until $\min (n, k)$, because you cannot have more $x_i s$ than $k$ or the number of available $x_i$ s.
(c) The left side of the equation represents the number of ways to select a $k$-subset from the set $Z=X \cup Y$, such that the subset contains no elements from $X$. This is done by considering all possible ways to exclude $i$ elements from $X$ and then choosing the remaining $k-i$ elements from $Y$ and the remaining elements of $X$, applying PIE to correct for overcounting.
When $m<k$, it is impossible to form a $k$-subset from $Y$ alone since there are not enough elements. Hence, the sum equals 0 in this case, as there are no valid subsets that meet the criteria.
When $m \geq k$, the situation aligns with simply choosing a $k$-subset from $Y$, since no elements from $X$ can be included. The number of such subsets is exactly $\left(\begin{array}{l}m \\ k\end{array}\right)$, as we're choosing $k$ elements from a set of $m$ elements.
(d) Consider a generating function for selecting items from $Y$ and $X$, where selecting an item from $Y$ contributes $y$ to the product (representing a choice from $Y$ ) and selecting an item from $X$ contributes $-x$ to the product (representing a choice to exclude from $X)$. The generating function for selecting $k$ items from $Z$ without any from $X$ can be written as the coefficient of $y^k$ in the expansion of $(1+y)^m(1-x)^n$, where $1+y$ accounts for choices from $Y$ and $1-x$ accounts for excluding choices from $X$.
Using the Binomial Theorem, $(1+y)^m=\sum_{j=0}^m\left(\begin{array}{c}m \\ j\end{array}\right) y^j$ and $(1-x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\left(\begin{array}{c}n \\ i\end{array}\right) x^i$. Multiplying these two expansions gives:
$$
(1+y)^m(1-x)^n=\left(\sum_{j=0}^m\left(\begin{array}{c}
m \\
j
\end{array}\right) y^j\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
i
\end{array}\right) x^i\right)
$$
The coefficient of $y^k$ in this product represents the number of ways to choose $k$ items from $Z$ without any from $X$. This coefficient can be found by considering all products of terms from the two expansions that result in $y^k$, which corresponds to choosing $k$ elements from $Y$ and some number of elements to exclude from $X$.
When $m<k$, there are not enough elements in $Y$ to form a $k$-subset, making the coefficient of $y^k$ equal to 0 . When $m \geq k$, the coefficient of $y^k$ comes solely from the term $y^k$ in the expansion of $(1+y)^m$ multiplied by the constant term 1 in the expansion of $(1-x)^n$, leading to a coefficient of $\left(\begin{array}{c}m \\ k\end{array}\right)$, which represents the number of ways to choose $k$ elements from $Y$.
